# Android Calendar Set Am or Pm time not 24 Hour

Tags: java, android

I have a script at the moment that is always being passed the time in an AM PM format. But I do not know how to set the calendar with this time as it only accepts 24 hour format the way I have the code written. How would I convert the time to 24 hour or input a 12 hour format?

```
         calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, HourValue);
         calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MinuteValue);
         calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -356);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR

calendar.set(calendar.HOUR,HourValue) ,  instead of HOUR_OF_DAY so if you give a 24 hour input it converts it into 12 hour format

Comment: Thank you how do you then define am or pm

Comment: calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, HourValue < 12 ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM) should do it

Comment: this answer saved my day :)

Answer (score 7):

0 for am and 1 for pm

    `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);`

Comment: Rather than use of 0 or 1, it's preferable to use `Calendar.AM` and `Calendar.PM`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int am_pm=c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
String time=c.HOUR + ((am_pm==Calendar.AM)?"am":"pm"))
```

you can try the above.

Answer (score 1):

Use below keyword to set AM / PM

**Calendar.AM**

**Calendar.PM**

```
val startDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                set(HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.AM) // Calendar.PM
                set(Calendar.HOUR, 9)
                set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
                set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            }.timeInMillis
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Determine today’s date for a given region.
        .plusDays( 1 ) ,                              // Determine day-after, tomorrow.
    LocalTime.parse(                                  // Parse string with AM/PM into `LocalTime` object.
        "6:51:35 PM" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "h:m:s a" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) 
    ) ,                                               // Combine date with time-of-day…
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )                   // …and zone…
)                                                     // …to produce a `ZonedDateTime`, a point on the timeline.
.toString()                                           // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format, wisely extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2018-02-02T18:51:35+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## java.time

Parse that incoming string in 12-hour format into a `LocalTime` object.

```
String input = "6:51:35 PM" ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "h:m:s a" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;

LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

To set your alarm, you'll need a date combined with this time-of-day along with a time zone to determine an actual moment.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Determine tomorrow by adding a day.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Apply the time-of-day and desired time zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. If your time-of-day is not valid for that date in that zone because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), the class automatically adjusts. Read the doc to be sure you understand and agree to the behavior of those adjustments.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , lt , z ) ; // Get a specific moment in time given a particular date, time-of-day, and zone.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).